# Can not access my WCF from IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, iis

I have created a WCF service that uses Entity Framework and it works perfectly on my local machine.

The issue is I cannot access it when i deploy it to IIS.

It runs fine in a browser but when I reference it from code I get this error:

"The underlying provider failed on Open"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do as it is saying, turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to get the details of error. Noone can help you, not even yourself, unless error is known

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. The error is "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Comment: post the exception in the question. entire exception including inner exception

Comment: I have now specified the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because the connection string that you are using is invalid. It works on local but doesn't have permissions to access from IIS. You need to alter your connection string.
For a list of possible problems and solutions visit this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2012/08/09/error-quot-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-quot-in-entity-framework-application.aspx).

Comment: My connection string is:   <add name="RisEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RisDataModel.csdl|res://*/RisDataModel.ssdl|res://*/RisDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=MVDEV02\SQL2005;initial catalog=&quot;RIS v2005-1&quot;;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: remove app=EntiryFramework

Comment: Did, but the problem still persists

Comment: Well there can be multiple reasons see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2012/08/09/error-quot-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-quot-in-entity-framework-application.aspx for resolution of all

Comment: Thanks a mil Ehsan. I changed the Windows connection string and used SQL authentication. I'm  a happy man as I speak

Comment: @PholosoMams hadn't you accepted it?

Comment: I tried but it says I have to have reputation before I rate it.I'll rate it later

Comment: @PholosoMams for accepting you don't need that. you can't upvote but you can accept.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 Reputation

Comment: @PholosoMams yes. that is why i am saying accept it as answer. Don't upvote as you can't.